# Different behaviour of function in a for-loop or when unrolling of the loop is performed

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I got an odd behaviour of my functions and since i'm not so used to matlab coding i guess is due to something really easy that i don't get.

I can't understand how this could print something different

```
fx(Punti(1,:),Punti(2,:))
fx(Punti(2,:),Punti(3,:))
fx(Punti(3,:),Punti(4,:))
fx(Punti(4,:),Punti(5,:))
```

from this

```
for i_unic=1:4
    fx(Punti(i_unic,:),Punti(i_unic+1,:))
end
```

Consider fx as a generic function.

Is it possible that fx uses some variables that for some reason are erased at the end of each iteration?

EDIT

-->"Punti" is just matrix containing the points a SCARA robot should follow

-->fx is the function "Retta" and it's the following

```
function retta(PuntoA,PuntoB,Asse_A,q_ini,rot,contaerro,varargin)
global SCARA40
global inizio XX YY ZZ
global seg_Nsteps
        npassi     =  seg_Nsteps;
        ipuntofin  =  inizio + npassi;
        for ipunto =  inizio : ipuntofin

        P4    = PuntoA + (ipunto-inizio)*(PuntoB-PuntoA)/npassi;
        q     = kineinversa(Asse_A,P4,q_ini,rot);
        Mec     = SCARA40.fkine(q);
        Pec     = Mec(:,4);
        if (dot((P4-Pec),(P4-Pec),3)>0.0001)
            fprintf(1,'\n P4 Desid.  = [%9.1f %9.1f %9.1f %9.1f ] \n',P4);        
            fprintf(1,'\n P4 Attuato = [%9.1f %9.1f %9.1f %9.1f ] \n',Pec); 
            contaerro = contaerro + 1;
        else
            q_ini   = q;
        end
        SCARA40.plot(q);
        XX(ipunto)   = Pec(1);
        YY(ipunto)   = Pec(2);
        ZZ(ipunto)   = Pec(3);
        if(nargin>6)
            color = varargin{1};
        else
            color = 'r';
        end
        plot3(XX,YY,ZZ,color,'LineWidth',1 );
        drawnow;
        hold on
        end
end
```

the test function with the results

```
Punti     = [  10,10,0,1 ;10,-10,0,1  ;-10,-10,0,1  ; -10,10,0,1 ] ;

%inizio=1
%retta(Punti(1,:)',Punti(2,:)',Asse_A,q_ini,rot,contaerro)
%inizio=21
%retta(Punti(2,:)',Punti(3,:)',Asse_A,q_ini,rot,contaerro)
%inizio=41
%retta(Punti(3,:)',Punti(4,:)',Asse_A,q_ini,rot,contaerro)
%inizio=61

inizio=1
for i=1:length(Punti)-1
retta(Punti(i,:)',Punti(i+1,:)',Asse_A,q_ini,rot,contaerro)
inizio=inizio+20;
end
```

[image: unfoalded loop][image: with for loop]

the two images have been generated restarting Matlab

Comment: The real reason is impossible to find out without you posting the code for `fx` (and also for `Punti` generation).

Comment: I can't post it, it's too long and no one would read it. 
Mine was a theoretical question, not code related.. it was: "can you find a reason why a function would behave in two different ways if it is in a for loop or if the unrorring of the loop has been performed?"
anyway It uses global variables and matlab classes if this information can help.

Comment: If the starting state of each of those snippets is exactly same, there should be no reason something "different" is output.  And without knowing how you called the snippets or how the globals and classes are used, I can't give you anymore information than that.

Comment: I think you've got another error somewhere else. Because IMO, there should really be NO difference. Please try to give a minimal working example, trim it down so that the effect still persists and then post the whole code at once.

Comment: _theoretically_ this _is_ possible. E.g. you can mess around with the for loop index from within the child function using [evalin](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) with `caller` workspace. There could be other ways, but we won't help you solve the actual problem unless you post the minimal code that reproduces the issue. Most likely the issue is somewhere else...

Comment: I posted the code, I hope now my question and the related problem is clear enough...
In C or C++ unless the index of the "for" is a global variable or a parameter , call three times a function in a loop or one after the other is exactly the same (i'm not talking about performances) and I was expecting the same behaviour in Matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing the question in the most general sense (since there is no sample given for the function `fx` or the function/variable `Punti`) then the reason you are getting different results is likely that the state of your variables/workspace is different when you test one case versus the other. How could this happen? Here are some obvious ways...

1. Your functions (or possibly other functions they call) are making use of the [random number generator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/random-number-generation.html), and the starting state of the RNG is different when you test the loop versus unrolled loop case.
2. Your functions are sharing global variables that aren't reset to some default value at the start of each test case. You mention in a comment that the functions use global variables, so this is likely your problem.
3. [Your functions aren't really functions, but scripts.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html) Scripts all share a common workspace (the [base workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html)), whereas a function (and specifically each call to a function) will have its own unique workspace. If `fx` is actually a script, each call may change any or all of the variables in the base workspace. Furthermore, any *other* scripts, or anything you type into the command line, can change things as well. The contents of the base workspace may therefore be different when you test the loop versus unrolled loop case.

If I were to hazard a guess, I'd say that if you were to exit and restart MATLAB before each test case (i.e. reset everything to the same default starting state) you would probably get the same exact result for the loop versus unrolled loop case.

Comment: I don't use any random generator, i restarted matlab and i'm sure that it's not a script.. :( i edited the first question, i added the pictures of the two different results, the test case and the function (i don't know if it's helpful since it's full of calls to other function). Thank you so much for the help! Hope the edit clarify the problem

Comment: I found the error! I incremented the variable "inizio" as it was local or not written by the function retta or by some subsequent call, but it was not the case!
so inizio = 21, inizio=41, ecc
was different from inizio=inizio+20, ecc because it was modified by some internal function